VS 2022: Package Installation Error when creating new .NET Web Application due to changed package location
Every time I create a new .NET Web application project in VS 2022, a package installation error shows up. The old location is from a corrupted HDD I removed. I've already set the correct location in RegEdit and it shows the correct location in the Visual Studio Installer and just re-installed Visual Studio but the changes don't take effect within VS itself. Anything I can do aside from a clean re-format of my OS?



